# Monitor Not Starting After First Boot

Tags: display, hardware-detection

My Computer starts when I press on power on but Monitor does not load and starts.
I Tried switching the monitor on/off still display is not detected.

When I restart my PC after that, the Monitor magically starts to work.
I observed this behavior for multiple days.

When I shutdown my PC overnight and start in morning, I face this issue.
Basically when PC is shutdown for longer period of time and then I try to start Monitor is not being detected and after restart it works as expected and if you try immediately after that by shutting down, then also it works.

Please guide me on how to diagnose and what can be the issue.

HardWare:
CPU: AMDFX8350
RAM: 16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 803MHz
Display : ASUSTeK Computer INC. M5A78L-M/USB3 (AM3R2)
DELL S2240L (1920x1080@59Hz)
Graphics : 3072MB ATI AMD Radeon R9 200 Series (XFX Pine Group)
Disks : 223GB KINGSTON SA400S37240G ATA Device (SATA-2 (SSD))
931GB Western Digital WDC WD10EZRX-00L4HB0 ATA Device (SATA)

Comment: Some information about the hardware would have been good.

Comment: Sure ill add more info about hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Could be your monitor is in sleep mode, see if you have a power save option on your monitor menu. Usually you have the menu on a side or bottom buttons on your monitor, sometimes near the power button

Comment: I checked, My Monitor does not have sleep mode option.